# How can I check if a dictionary contains a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a function that return true if in my dictionary contain another dictionary.

```
for k in dictObj.iteritems():
    if k contain dictionary return false
    else return true
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: So `{'foo': {}}` should return False here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop over the *values* (so over `dict.itervalues()` or `dict.values()`, depending on your Python version), and use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to test each. Combine that with the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and a generator expression to make it efficient:

```
return any(isinstance(v, dict) for v in dictObj.itervalues())
```

Demo:

```
>>> dictObj = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> any(isinstance(v, dict) for v in dictObj.itervalues())
False
>>> dictObj = {'foo': {'spam': 'eggs'}}
>>> any(isinstance(v, dict) for v in dictObj.itervalues())
True
```

If you want to detect any *mapping* type (not just dictionaries), you could test for [`collections.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Mapping) instead of `dict`; this would let you handle any alternative mapping implementations too.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for something like this

```
def has_inner_dict(d):
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            return True
    return False
```